# $Push operation on field defined as object in mongoose schema is not giving error

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a mongoose model defined as

```
const definedSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  fieldA1: { type: String },
  fieldA2: { type: String },
  fieldA3: { type: Date },
});
const schema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    fieldA: { type: definedSchema },
    fieldB: { type: definedSchema },
    fieldC: { type: definedSchema },
  }
);
const model = mongoose.model('model', schema);
```

Now I am performing update operation on the model by using below code -

```
let updatedData = await model.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: id },
    {
      $push: {
        fieldA: {
          fieldA1,
          fieldA2,
          fieldA3,
        },
      },
    },
    {
      new: true,
      session: mongoSession,
    },
  );
```

No error is generated by mongoose on performing push on object field.
And in MongoDB compass also the fieldA is shown to be stored as an array with multiple objects.

But when I fetched data from the collection and tried to update fieldB and fieldC using below code-

```
const data = await model.findOne({
    filter,
});
obj.fieldB=x;
obj.fieldC=y;
await obj.save();
```

I got an error

```
ValidationError: model validation failed: fieldA: Tried to set nested object field `fieldA` to array `[object Object]` and strict mode is set to throw .
```

But when I update the fieldB and fieldC using finByIdAndUpdate it is working fine

```
await model.findByIdAndUpdate(id,
        {
          fieldA,
          fieldB
        });
```

Not able to understand

1. how push operation can work on object field without generating error ?
2. why updating using findByIdAndUpdate is working and not .save() operation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `save()`, validation is turned on by default, but for update methods like `findByIdAndUpdate`, validation is turned off by default, and should be turned on if needed, by passing `runValidators: true` as an option, like so:

```js
  let updatedData = await model.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: id },
    {
      $push: {
        fieldA: {
          fieldA1,
          fieldA2,
          fieldA3,
        },
      },
    },
    {
      new: true,
      session: mongoSession,
      runValidators: true,
    },
  );
```

For reference, take a look at the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#update-validators)